# Confusion about nLab's definition of smooth $\infty$-groupoid

Tags: sheaf-theory, higher-category-theory, grothendieck-topologies

[This nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+infinity-groupoid#definition) defines (in Definition 2.6) a smooth $\infty$-groupoid as an $(\infty,1)$-sheaf on the $(\infty,1)$-category $C = \text{CartSp}_{\text{smooth}}$ whose objects are Cartesian spaces, arrows are smooth maps between them, 2-cells are smooth homotopies, and so on.

I assume this is with respect to an $(\infty,1)$-site structure on $C$.

However, the linked article above only seems to describe (in Definition 2.5) a site structure on the strict 1-category $C_{\leq1}$ of the ("1-strict") $(\infty,1)$-category $C$.

I was wondering, given the Grothendieck topology on $C_{\leq1}$, is there a "canonical" choice of $(\infty,1)$-Grothendieck topology on $C$? Is this being used implicitly in the above nLab page?

Comment: $C$ is a $1$-category, not an $\infty$-category, at least according to the [definition in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/CartSp).

Comment: By "not an $\infty$-category", I mean that there is no nontrivial higher structure.

Comment: @Yai0Phah But the [nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+infinity-groupoid#definition) I linked to discussses (in Definition 2.6) $(\infty,1)$-sheaves on $C$, which only makes sense if $C$ is an $(\infty,1)$-site.

Comment: An 1-site is also an $(\infty,1)$-site, and even for an $\infty$-category, the Grothendieck topology on it only depends on the homotopy category, which could be found in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory.

Comment: @Yai0Phah I see; so an $(\infty,1)$-site structure on $C$ corresponds to a 1-site structure on the homotopy category h$C$? If so, how does the usual 1-site structure on $C_{\leq1}$ push down to a Grothendieck topology on h$C$?

Comment: @Yai0Phah Oh I see; we are using a $C$ without any higher structures? So that $C$, its 1-truncation, and its homotopy category are all equal?

Comment: That truncation is same as taking the homotopy category. This could also be found in Lurie's book.

Comment: @Yai0Phah But if $C$ had higher cells, the homotopy 1-category (obtained by identifying 1-cells connected by a 2-cell) would not agree with the 1-category obtained by forgetting n-cells for n≥2 (which is a category since composition of 1-cells in $C$ is strict), without identifying any 1-cells? However, in this case these are the same, since $C$ has no higher cells?

Comment: The $n$-truncation of an $\infty$-category is defined in HTT, §2.3.4.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Lurie says in 2.3.4.14 that $h_1C$ is (the nerve of) the homotopy 1-category $hC$. I think I understand that if $C$ has no nontrivial higher cells, then $h_1C$ should be isomorphic to $C$. If I'm understanding correctly, if $C$ did have higher cells, then $h_1C$ would not be isomorphic to $C$?